# Realm IllegalStateException

Tags: android, realm, instance

I'm trying to use realm as a persistence method of the downloaded data from an API. I'm getting the error: *

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Realm instance has
>   already been closed, making it unusable.

and I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the persistence methods. My class for persistence is the next:

```
public class PersistenceManager {

    @Inject
    public PersistenceManager(){}

    public void saveHabitants(final List<Habitant> habitants){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); // opens db
        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(habitants);
                }
            });
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }

    }

    public void saveHabitant(final Habitant habitant){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        try {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {
                    realm.insertOrUpdate(habitant);
                }
            });
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }

    }

    public List<Habitant> loadHabitants(){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        List<Habitant> results;

        try {
            results = realm.where(Habitant.class).findAll();
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }

        return results;
    }

    public List<Habitant> loadHabitants(int indexFrom, int limit){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        List<Habitant> results;

        try {
            results = realm.where(Habitant.class).findAll();
            results.subList(indexFrom, limit);
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }

        return results;
    }

    public Habitant loadHabitant(long id){

        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Habitant result;

        try {
            result = realm.where(Habitant.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
        } finally {
            realm.close();
        }

        return result;
    }


}
```

When I used the method `loadHabitants(int indexFrom, int limit)` is when I get this error.

Answer (score 1):

A RealmResults is accessible through lazy loading (per accessor) for as long as there is at least 1 open Realm instance on the given thread.

I actually intended to refer to the documentation, but for some reason I couldn't find it? Anyways, a RealmResults is accessed lazily, so when there are no open Realm instances, it becomes invalid, and can no longer be accessed. This is true for RealmObjects as well.

[The docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle) do say:

> ...RealmObjects and RealmResults are accessed through a lazy cache...

so you cannot return a managed RealmResults, and expect it to remain open, if you close the thread-local Realm instance it is associated with.

---

Two solutions:

1.) refer to the [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#realm-instance-lifecycle) on how to properly manage Realm lifecycle on UI thread and background thread

2.) use `realm.copyFromRealm()`, which eagerly evaluates the whole data set, creates a detached copy of it. Please note that this is not a free operation, larger data sets can easily cause UI thread to freeze up if you use `copyFromRealm()` on UI thread.

```
public List<Habitant> loadHabitants(int indexFrom, int limit){
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
        List<Habitant> results = realm.where(Habitant.class).findAll();
        results = new ArrayList<>(results.subList(indexFrom, limit));
        for(int i = 0, size = results.size(); i < size; i++) {
            results.set(i, realm.copyFromRealm(results.get(i)));
        }
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(results);
    }
}
```